# How to delete entity and all associated entities in one @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpql

I have Restaurant entity that has List of Vote and Dish.
Both of them are @OneToMany

```java
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Dish> dishes;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Vote> votes;

}
```

Cascade delete perform multiple SQLs, I want to write @Query myself. It should delete Dishes and Vote first. They have restaurant_id, then - Vote. So that I have no ConstraintViolation exception.

Could you please show me an example of this JPQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of @Modifying annotation on top of @Query annotation. @Modifying annotation makes JPQL perform not only SELECT queries but also UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT.

For e.g. in your RestaurantJPARepository class, create a method like below

```java
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Restaurant r WHERE r.id =:id")
void deleteRestaurant(@Param("id") String id);
```

Comment: The question was how could this be done without many SQL queries.
It has modifying and works now but with a ton of SQLs

Comment: In my opinion, `DELETE FROM Restaurant r WHERE r.id =:id` is just one SQL command.